# Prove that $T$ is not contraction and $T^2$ is contraction

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

[[image: Prove that <span class=]$T$ is not contraction and $T^2$ is  contraction">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3eFS.png)

For (a) $||(Tf)(t)-(Tg)(t)||= ||\int ^t_0 f(s)ds-\int ^t_0 g(s)ds||\\
=||\int ^t_0(f(s)-g(s))ds||\\=\sup_{0\le t\le 1}|\int ^t_0(f(s)-g(s))ds| \\ \le\sup_{0\le t\le 1} \int^t_0|f(s)-g(s)|ds  $

From here how we contradict that $T$ is not contraction and how to we processed for (b) and (c)

thank you ...

Comment: Are you sure the title reflects the question...? Or is it a deliberately inversed problem? ;)

Comment: @CiaPan.. ho yeah sorry i edited now thank  you very much

Comment: To show that something is *not* a contraction you only need to find specific distinct $f, g$ so that $\|Tf - Tg\| \geq \|f - g\|$.

Comment: @MeesdeVries..you are right but i can't find those f and g

Comment: @MeesdeVries that is sufficient, but not necessary and in fact never holds..

Comment: @UmbertoP., yes, thank you, corrected.

Comment: @InverseProblem here is a way to get started: if $f(t) = 0$ and $g(t) = 1$ then $\|Tf - Tg\| = \|f-g\| = 1$. On the other hand, for any $f$ and $g$ you have $Tf(0) = Tg(0) = 0$.

Comment: @InverseProblem OK, but you thought about it for less than two minutes.

Comment: The question about fixed point seems to be nonsensical. $T$ is obviously linear. It would be more sensible to ask whether $1$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

Answer (score 1):

For (a), you should try to find a counter-example. For example, for any given $g(t)\in C[0,1]$, we can set $f(t)=g(t)+1$. Then you can show that $T$ is not contraction.

For (b), you can use the mean value theorem.
\begin{equation}
||T^2 f-T^2g|| = \sup_{t\in [0,1]} |\int_0^t \int_0^s f(u)-g(u) \mathrm{d}u \mathrm{d}s| = |f(\xi)-g(\xi)| \sup_{t\in [0,1]}\frac{1}{2}t^2 \leq ||f-g||
\end{equation}

For (c), I think we should first try to prove that C[0,1] is a Banach space and then apply fixed point theorem to get the answer.